# Science sites are no longer listed in the footer

Tags: bug, status-completed, footer

I just noticed today that the Science SE sites are no longer listed in the footer, with just the `more` left. Is this intended?

[image: Science is missing!]

Comment: EEEK! SE has become a religion!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Well... this is awkward. [Christianity SE](http://christianity.stackexchange.com) graduated today and pushed Science over:

[image]

We'll get it sorted out tomorrow. In the meantime, [check out Jin's beautiful design for Christianity](http://christianity.stackexchange.com) and try not to read too much into the bug...

Comment: Design looks awesome! The footer background image is *pretty* big though.

Comment: Love the design! Especially the Children of the Corn inspired footer ;P

Comment: There's a joke in there somewhere. Didn't even see that they were just pushed over, d'oh! And fantastic design on Christianity indeed!

Comment: Not reading into this is no fun. Personally I'm pretty sure the SE design team is trying to start a holy war by playing off a stereotype. OUT PITCHFORKS!

Comment: The code calculating the column of each header is not taking into account the extra "site" for each category, which is the "more" link.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Correct. But it does now. Sowwy.

Comment: @Oded I had a feeling you're behind this bug but didn't want to throw accusations near your boss. ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yeah. With Christianity graduating, this was the first time we had a category with an _exact_ multiple of 8...

Comment: @Oded yep, I call this a time bomb bug. :D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - and pure coincidence that it was Christianity :)