# Why hasn't Christianity made it into the Data Explorer yet?

Tags: support, status-completed, data-explorer, graduating-sites

[Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) officially graduated at the end of May. A [question on our local meta](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1748/30) asked when we could expect to see our site show up in the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). The [response](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1749/30) was that it might lag a week or so.

I've been watching and the data dumps have been updated 3 times on an apparently weekly rotation now but I haven't seen the C.SE dump added to the set yet.
Did some bit not get set? Does it need poking?

Comment: It's just payback for the science displacement snafu.

Comment: @waxeagle Would it help if we got the Pope to apologize for [making science step aside](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182260/145951)? If we can't get him would some lesser figure do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There was a `NULL` vs `''` issue on the automatic site import process that runs as part of the weekly refresh.  It has been fixed and a data refresh is running now.  Since we go back to front, the Christianity data is already populated, enjoy!